# Skype doesn't auto-run at startup

Tags: windows, boot, skype

I'm running Vista SP2 and Skype 4.1.0.141.

I have "Start Skype when I start Windows" checked, but it's still not starting automatically. Is this a Skype bug, or something I can track down myself?

**UPDATE:** I've just upgraded from .141 to .179 and the problem is back, with the registry entry corrupted as before. Again, fixing the registry entry as described seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I have a solution, but I can't see any way that the problem could have arisen, except for a buggy skype installer .

msconfig was listing the command to run as:-

```
"C:\Program Files\Skype\\Phone\Skype.exe"  /nosplash /minimized
```

Note the **double slash** in there before `Phone`!

Changing the registry entry for `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Skype` to remove the extra slash fixed the problem.

Comment: Excelent. It was the problem for me as well (Vista x64). To make things harder, autoruns did not display the double backslash, only a single one, therefore I missed the problem. This time I have used regedit and the problem was obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting a shortcut to Skype in your startup folder

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Vista SP2. I used the same trick for when the Microsoft updates got stuck:

I deleted everything regarding Skype from the hosts.

1. Navigate to the following location:

   Windows 95/98/Me:

   ```
   %Windir%
   ```

   Windows NT/2000/XP:

   ```
   %Windir%\System32\drivers\etc
   ```

   Windows Vista:

   ```
   c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
   ```
2. Double-click the hosts file.
3. If necessary, deselect the “Always use this program to open this program” check box.
4. Scroll through the list of programs and double-click Notepad.
5. When the file opens, delete all the (Skype) entries.
6. Save.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Skype shortcut which is in desktop (OR) right click on "Skype" which is in Start-->Program menu.. then,

Select Properties -> Compatibility tab. Uncheck the option “Run this program as an administrator”. Save by pressing OK button.

It will fix 2 problems.

1. Auto start up of skype during system starts
2. Drag and Drop (send file) in the conversation window will work.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution solves these two problems that appear in Skype when installed on Win7 Pro x64. I cannot believe it was *this* simple.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Skype shortcut which is on the desktop (OR) right click on "Skype" which is in Start → Programs

In the Compatibility tab under "Run program in Compatibility mode" choose your version. If you are using Vista or Windows 7, then press apply.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
Run --> msconfig [enter]
startups tab
check on in skype check box
Ok
Restart your computer.
```

Comment: Should be 'msconfig' rather than 'mstsc'.

Comment: Tom: Yup. Corrected. Been a while, since I used Windows.

Comment: Tried that - checkbox was already ticked... :-(

Answer (score 0):

When installing Skype 4.1, its base library `Skype4COM.dll` (version of 2009) is being stored in `?:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype` but old version of `Skype4COM.dll` (of 2007) had been stored in `\Windows\system32`. After disabling startup of the new version, Skype starts by means of old library. The records of both libraries are in registry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls` (all listed dlls run at Windows startup, old `Skype4COM.dll` runs as if disabled Skype).

The method of curing:

- Exit Skype
- Delete both records from `....\SharedDlls` key
- Restart in safe mode, delete old `Skype4COM.dll` from `system32`
- Restart Windows (Skype must not start if it was diasbled in settings)
- Run Skype manually and set option "run at Windows startup"

Comment: Maybe a different problem. I don't have the old DLL on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this for ages as my Skype stopped autolaunching with a 2017 update, so although this is a slight variation to the question (it's a different version of Skype and for Wimdows 10) this was the ONLY thread anywhere that I found that dealt with the problem so am posting a solution here for others still looking (ironically most other results were for how to STOP Skype from auto-launching!) The link below shows you how to add apps to the start-up folder in Windows 10:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026268/windows-change-startup-apps-in-windows-10

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If the help at the link you included solved the same problem for you, please [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1314730/edit) to include the essential steps here- if the link changes or disappears your answer becomes useless. Thanks :)