# Skype does not start on Vista 64

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting, boot, skype

I have a computer with Vista 64 and I have a problem with Skype on it. It does not start automatically. I have checked the corresponding option in the Skype settings (Start Skype when I start Windows) is ticked.

What troubleshooting steps could I try to find why it does not start?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/16220/skype-doesnt-auto-run-at-startup - the solution there worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have un-ticked the "Start Skype when I start Windows" option, terminated Skype, launched it and ticked it again. Since then it starts on its own. No idea what was wrong.

---

Well, sometimes it does start, sometimes it does not. Still no idea what was wrong or how to fix it.

---

The solution from [Skype doesn't auto-run at startup](https://superuser.com/questions/16220/skype-doesnt-auto-run-at-startup/18407#18407) has worked for me as well. To make things harder, SysInternals autoruns did not display the double backslash, only a single one, therefore I missed the problem when inspecting the issue with it. This time I have used regedit and the problem was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally seen this issue and Skype works (And starts) on a x64 machine I use, however, apart from a repair install (in case something is corrupt), there are two options available to you:

1. Simply place a shortcut to Skype in the `Startup` Program group.
2. Set a scheduled task to launch Skype upon logon.

Comment: In the end I did this, as everything else I have tried was unreliable. The only drawback is even if I set startup shortcut properties as run minimized, it still opens the Skype window every time. Better than not having Skype running without me knowing it, still.