# Skype "Automatically start Skype" Setting Keeps Turning Off

Tags: windows-10, skype

I am trying to set Skype to start with Windows with the setting: setting dialog -> General  -> Automatically Start Skype -> Settings -> (Startup Apps Dialog) -> Skype -> Switch On

However, after a reboot (or possibly a few reboots) Skype is back to not starting up with Windows again and the setting appears as off.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Most probably it's being disabled by policy setting or another script/task that disables it. With the info you provided it's no way to give more precise answer.

Comment: @Hardoman Thank you.  Do you have any suggestions on how to go about finding the problem task/script?

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed before, please kindly check if it was helpful to you: [Skype doesn't auto-run at startup](https://superuser.com/questions/16220/skype-doesnt-auto-run-at-startup?rq=1)

Comment: @Sunny Thank you.  I had checked these but did not list them as the details no longer apply to the current version of Skype. I tried a reinstall.  I will post if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Toaster there are too many possibilities here. I would start checking everything at startup, Windows Task Scheduler and applied policies via gpresult. I would also try changing the startup option via registry. There would be a possibility that you enable it on account level (HKCU), but it's disabled for all users (HKLM). Check all startup possibilities https://lazyadmin.nl/it/windows-10-startup-folder-location/

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the mechanism behind this problem; however, uninstall and reinstall appears to have solved the issue.